# How to convert a function from PHP Procedural to PHP MVC?

Tags: php, codeigniter, procedural-programming

I have this function on my View Page, which truncates some data to present it on my table.

```
function truncate($mytext) {  
    //Number of characters to show  
    $chars = 100;  
    $mytext = substr($mytext,0,$chars);  
    $mytext = substr($mytext,0,strrpos($mytext,' '));    
    return $mytext;  
    }
```

I set a local variable for my dynamic text:

```
$mydescription = $value['PROBLEM_DESCRIPTION']
```

On the same page, I have this:

```
echo '<td><p>' .truncate($mydescription). '; ?></p><</td>
```

And it works perfect, so my question is how can apply this on an MVC architecture using Codeigniter?
If somebody has an idea let me know, thanks!!!

Comment: CodeIgniter does not implement MVC design pattern, so what the hell are you even talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in the controller:

```
class Something extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){
        $data['mytext'] = $this->_truncate('some text to truncate');

        //truncated text will be available in the view as $mytext
        $this->load->view('some_view', $data);
    }

    private function _truncate($text = NULL){
        if($text){
            $chars = 100;  
            $mytext = substr($text,0,$chars);  
            $mytext = substr($text,0,strrpos($text,' ')); 
            return $mytext;
        }  
    }
}
```

---

### Edit:

You are calling db stuff in your view which is entirely not Codeigniter MVC.

This is what it might look like in MVC:

### Controller

```
class Something extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){
        $test_text = $this->my_model->get_text();
        $data['test_text'] = $this->_truncate($test_text);

        //truncated text will be available in the view as $test_text
        $this->load->view('some_view', $data);
    }

    private function _truncate($text = NULL){
        if($text){
            $chars = 100;  
            $mytext = substr($mytext,0,$chars);  
            $mytext = substr($mytext,0,strrpos($mytext,' ')); 
            return $mytext;
        }  
    }
}
```

### Model

```
class My_Model extends CI_Model{

    public function get_text(){
        //$this->db->get_where....or other db functions
        return "testing text... this is only a test";
    }

}
```

### View

```
<html>
<body>
<b><?php echo $test_text; ?></b>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried your code, but in my View how can I use this? You have to remember that im sending 1 value to be evaluate in this function

Comment: Typically in MVC (Codeigniter) the dynamic text that is in the view comes from the controller. The controller talks to the model if necessary to grab data, and sends it to the view. The comment I have there explains how it would be called in the view.

Comment: In this case, im trying to send a value back from the View to be evaluate it on the controller. Am I doing this right? `echo '<td><p>' .$mytext($mydescription). '; ?></p><</td>`

Comment: No. How did the text get to the view? Are you hard coding it in there? Is it dynamic? **Typically** dynamic text begins its life in the controller (usually via model). If you have dynamic text instantiated in the view, you are doing it wrong. Please edit your post and include the controller and view you are using.

Comment: It is dynamic text from my DB, then in my view I declared a local variable, so I can use it on my function: `$mydescription = $value['PROBLEM_DESCRIPTION']`

Comment: Yeah, dynamic text from db traditionally travels through the controller first. Move the db code in your view to the controller. PLEASE POST THE CONTROLLER AND VIEW.

Comment: My DB function works through the Model/Controller/View, i dont have a problem with that. My problem is with this function

Comment: I've added an example to the answer; see if that clears things up. See also: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/overview/mvc.html

Comment: I know the whole idea is to send "formatted text" to the view, but that's why im trying to move that function to my controller, thanks anyway i'll try to work with this

Comment: Dunno how else to help you... try reading up on codeigniter MVC; look at some code. The example I've provided gets the data from the db, formats it with `_truncate()`, then sends it to the view to display....

Answer (score 2):

You should at least define this function as a method of your model (where you take this description from).

```
class TextModel extends CI_Model {
   ...
   public function getShortDescription(){
       $chars = 100;  
       $mytext = substr($this->mytext,0,$chars);  
       $mytext = substr($mytext,0,strrpos($mytext,' '));    
       return $mytext;
   }
}
```

And the in your controller smth along the lines of:

```
class Blog extends Controller {

    function index()
    {
            $this->load->model('TextModel');
        $data['short_description'] = $this->TextModel->getShortDescription();

        $this->load->view('blogview', $data);
    }
}
```

And at last, in your view:

```
echo '<td><p>'.$short_description.'</p></td>';
```

I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter, but I guess any data manipulation should be done in models, thus you will keep your controllers 'thin' and won't violate MVC paradigm.

Comment: I like your approach, i read before about the 'Thin' Controller and 'Fat' Model, but how can I send my data to be evaluate it on this function?

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have a working code, all you need to decide is where in the MVC paradigm of CI should this be transferred to. I would suggest putting this inside a [helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html). Helpers in CI are just what the name suggests, a simple php file with a bunch of functions that help you to get certain tasks done. Suppose you put this inside a file called 'utility.php' You could then include this file wherever you need using

```
$this->load->helper('utility');
```

and then call the truncate function.

Now, if you have a bunch of related tasks which you want to neatly organize in a class based structure you could create your own CI [library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html). Suppose you created a library named 'truncate', then similar to helpers these are loaded as

```
$this->load->library('truncate');
```

Personally, for a bunch of utilities I would just put them all into a helper instead of extending core CI classes or creating a custom library.

Answer (score 0):

Controller: create a controller **truncate.php**.

```
<?php
 Class Truncate extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
 }

 function truncate_text($mytext) {  
     //Number of characters to show
     $chars = 100;
     if(empty($mytext))
         echo '$mytext is empty.';
     $mytext = substr($mytext,0,$chars);  
     $data['mytext'] = substr($mytext,0,strrpos($mytext,' '));    
     $this->load->view('truncate_view',$data);
 }
```

View: create a view file **truncate_view.php**

```
<?php
    echo '<td><p>'.$mytext.'</p></td>';
   //Write your other view code if any are present.
?>
```

Comment: I like the simplicity on this one, but my values are showing NULL, also shouldn't be like `echo '<td><p>' .$mytext($mydescription). '; ?></p><</td>`

Comment: @cyberjas2001: Thank u. Anywayz I guess I don't have to edit my answer now. :)

Answer (score 0):

The current answers explain that you can add the method to the model and also the controller. 
Functionally, this is no problem, as you said the function works perfectly wherever you place it.

What happens when you need to call the same method in another controller? Or with a different model?

It is most likley you will end up with some code duplication.

As a possible soultion, you could create a library of classes that allow you to keep all you string
manipulation in one place. Simply add more methods to your class...

```
// example/libary/path/TextFormatter.php
class TextFormatter
{
  protected $_text = '';

  public function __construct($text)
  {
    $this->_text = $text;

    return $this;
  }

  public function truncate($maxChars = 100)
  {
    $truncated = substr($this->_text, 0, $maxChars);  
    $truncated = substr($truncated, 0, strrpos($truncated,' '));    

    return $truncated;
  }

  public function stripHtml()
  {
    ///.....
  }

  public function doSomethingElseWithText()
  {

  }

}
```

Then in the controller...

```
// Controller.php

class SomeController extends Controller
{

  public function index()
  {
    $formatter = new TextFormatter('Example text string');  
    $data['formattedText'] = $formatter->truncate();

  }


}
```

The only caveat is the `TextFormatter` class needs to be autoloaded/callable from wherever you use it.